# when using Image object, It's more slower than to use buffer object

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to use Image object for image processing.

I compared  image object processing time with buffer object processing time.

I found that image object is more slower than buffer object in YUV420.

I processed separately Y and UV because of Data Size.

Y is a original size, UV is a quarter of original image size.

So, I used cl_image_format like that

- Y : image_channel_order = CL_R,  image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8
- UV : image_channel_order = CL_RG, image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8

I thought that image object is more faster buffer object when processing image.

But, It was really an unexpected result.

I don't know the reasons.

I think image object take more bit size than buffer object with 24 bit.

but, I can't sure.

Comment: Could you please show the relevant code? It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your access pattern. For coalesced reads, a buffer is fastest, but for non-coalesced reads it is slower than using images. You can work around that using shared local memory as a cache.

Images use the texture cache that is optimized for spatial locality. So for nearby reads -- horizontally or vertically -- it can be faster than buffers.

You don't show any code, but if you're seeing better speed with buffers then you must have coalesced reads. If you changed your access pattern then it might be the other way around.